# Аналог Win + R в Windows?

Tags: windows

Аналог Win + R в Windows с историей, автодополнением, запуском установленных приложений?

Comment: Пока найден только Google Desktop Search

Comment: Я знаю что только с памяткой есть.
Лучший вариант - поиск win7 там просто win жмешь и он все ищет что вводить начинаешь.

Comment: есть еще MuvEnum address bar но она бывает падает на win xp

Comment: Windows search?

Answer (score 2):

[SlickRun](http://www.fiddlertool.com/SlickRun/), ее можно даже к Win+R прикрутить ([How to get SlickRun to activate with Windows-R](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToGetSlickRunToActivateWithWindowsR.aspx)). Можно также глянуть на [Launchy](http://alternativeto.net/software/launchy/) и кучу других [альтернатив](http://alternativeto.net/software/launchy/).